# Flutter How to make a column screen scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

````dart
             Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 7,
                            width: 70,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("Düzenle"),
                        ),
                        trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("Sustur"),
                        ),
                        trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("Alarm Al "),
                        ),
                        trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("Sms Al"),
                        ),
                        trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("E-Posta Al"),
                        ),
                        trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ```
````

Comment: You can wrap your `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SingleChildScrollView`

Like so:

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          leading: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Düzenle"),
          ),
          trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Sustur"),
          ),
          trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Alarm Al "),
          ),
          trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Sms Al"),
          ),
          trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("E-Posta Al"),
          ),
          trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```